# Swift MKAnnotationView maskToBounds throwing error

Tags: ios, swift

**Problem**
Currently I am trying to add a custom image to an AnnotationPoint. I currently have it working, but I would like to add rounded edges to it. When I try to set the codes maskToBounds = true, I get an error thrown (I believe because it is being called in the main thread). When I try to make a temporary AnnotationView, in the viewDidLoad I set it's masksToBounds property to true, and it works, but only for 1 persons image, and when I zoom in on the map it will disappear. What I would like help with is figuring out what to do to fix the error

**What I have Tried**

```
    //sets the pictures on the map from a url
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {
        if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
            return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "Profile Picture"

        var anView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
        if anView == nil {
            anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            anView.canShowCallout = true
        }
        else {
            anView.annotation = annotation
        }

        //Set annotation-specific properties **AFTER**
        //the view is dequeued or created...
        let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
        if let url = NSURL(string: cpa.urlName) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url){
                anView.image =  UIImage(data: data)
            }

    }

        //resize the users friends profile pictures
        var cropSquare = CGRectMake(0, 0, anView.image.size.width / 3, anView.image.size.height / 3)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropSquare.size, false, 1.0)
        anView.image.drawInRect(cropSquare)
        anView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        anView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        anView.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        return anView
}
```

**The Error**
Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    //make the images circles
    var imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: anView.image)
    var layer: CALayer = CALayer()
    layer = imageView.layer
    layer.masksToBounds = true
    layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(anView.image.size.width / 2)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.bounds.size)
    layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    var roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    anView.image = roundedImage
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```